# Select value in another table if reference is found

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Alright, I'm pretty desperate. This is my first time using StackOverflow (I've always find all my answer but not this time). Please Community I need your help cause I'm not a SQL wiz. (I'm using Access).

I have 3 tables "User", "Type" and "User_update". I want to get the value from the "User" table but if there's an update for that user in the "User_update" table I would like to have the value from the "User_update" table instead and the date of the update. :-/

```
TABLE "USER"
id | user | type_id
--------------------
0  | bibi | 1
1  | toto | 1

TABLE "TYPE"
id | type
-----------
0  | admin
1  | normal

TABLE "USER_UPDATE"
id | user_id | type_id | date
-----------------------------------
0  | 1       | 0       | 9/3/2015
```

Would like to get something like this:

```
user | type   | date
--------------------
bibi | normal | 
toto | admin  | 9/3/2015
```

Hope you guys can help!

Comment: COALESCE?   I'll have a look at this cause I've never seen this before. (I'm a newbie to SQL). Thanks jarlh!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Access, but here's an ANSI SQL answer:

```
select coalesce(uu.user, u.user), t.type, uu.date
from user u
    left join user_update uu on u.id = uu.id
    join type t on t.id = coalesce(uu.type_id, u.type_id)
```

The `LEFT JOIN` is there to read from `user_update` if a matching row is found. `COALESCE` returns the first non-null value, so if a `user_update` has been found that value is returned, otherwise `user` value is returned.

**NOTE:** In ANSI SQL `date` and `user` are reserved words, so these may need to be delimited, e.g. `"date"` or perhaps `[date]`.

**Access attempts:**

```
select coalesce(uu.user, u.user), t.type, uu.date
from (user u
      left join user_update uu on (u.id = uu.id))
     join type t on (t.id = coalesce(uu.type_id, u.type_id))
```

Or perhaps:

```
select coalesce(uu.user, u.user), t.type, uu.date
from type t
     join (user u
           left join user_update uu on (u.id = uu.id))
     on (t.id = coalesce(uu.type_id, u.type_id))
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer @jarlh (I'm really impressed with the rapidity of your help). I've been fiddling with it... to add the delimiter but keep getting an error. Here's the request I'm trying:
    SELECT COALESCE(uu.user, u.user), t.type, uu.[date]
    FROM [user] u
    LEFT JOIN user_update uu ON u.id = uu.id
    JOIN type t ON t.id = COALESCE(uu.type_id, u.type_id)

When I run it I get this message : " Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'u.id = uu.id JOIN type t ON t.id = COALESCE(uu.type_id, u.type_id'.  "

:-(

Comment: oups... the formatting doesn't work in the comment section. :-/

Comment: Perhaps Access requires ( ) around each JOIN?

Comment: Not sure I'm placing the () at the right place. I get Syntax error in JOIN operation.

SELECT COALESCE(uu.user, u.user), t.type, uu.[date] FROM [user] u LEFT JOIN (user_update uu ON u.id = uu.id) JOIN (type t ON t.id = COALESCE(uu.type_id, u.type_id))

Comment: I'll give it a try, back in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

As someone new to access, I would recommend you design most of your queries using the "Design View".  You want to left join the USER table on both tables, using the USER.type_id = TYPE.id and USER.user = USER_UPDATE.user

The following SQL should accomplish what you want, returning the "USER_UPDATE" record should it have a value, otherwise it will return the "TYPE" record.

You will need to look to see if there can be multiple records in "USER_UPDATE" for the same user, depending on your use, the return of multiple records may not be what you are looking for, you will need to build a select query to return only the most recent record in "USER_UPDATE"

```
SELECT USER.id, USER.user, USER.type_id, IIf([USER_UPDATE].[type] Is Null, [type].[type],[USER_UPDATE].[type]) AS user_type, USER_UPDATE.date
FROM ([USER] LEFT JOIN TYPE ON USER.type_id = TYPE.id) LEFT JOIN USER_UPDATE ON USER.user = USER_UPDATE.user;
```